# Как добавить в сериализованный объект еще одно значение?

Tags: javascript

```
var formData = $(th).closest('form').serialize();
```

Таким образом пробовал: `formData.push({name: 'work'});`

Comment: До бональности просто:

    formData += '&newKey=newVal';

Comment: @Deonis, с нелатинскими символами и пробелами этот трюк не пройдет, нужен будет encodeURI как минимум.  
Надежней всего будет засунуть лишний инпут в форму и отсериализовать заново.

Comment: @Etki, возможно. У меня случаев таких не было, но [песочница говорит об обратном][1].

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/q3625/1/

Comment: @Deonis, я на бэкенде так и не опробовал, но что-то мне подсказывает, что он отвалится:

![](http://i.imgur.com/TChCBK2.png)

Comment: @Etki, опять же скажу, что точно не знаю, но вполне возможно и скорее всего в каких-то определенных случаяй. Но уже взял психонул и запустил в реальных условиях, а оно зараза не отваливается ;)